# gradle signingReport Build fail

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to create a SHA1 key from Gradle, but everytime I use  `gradle signingReport`, I get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Users/dcl/Desktop/Mobile Apps/QuizFusion/android/settings.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'android'.
> Could not open dsl generic class cache for script '/Users/dcl/Desktop/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/app_plugin_loader.gradle' (/Users/dcl/.gradle/caches/7.5/scripts/2b2truhe447thkmu9cehwsnd4).
   > BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 65

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

this is my Gradle and JVM version.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-07-14 12:48:15 UTC
Revision:     c7db7b958189ad2b0c1472b6fe663e6d654a5103

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          21.0.1 (Oracle Corporation 21.0.1+12-LTS-29)
OS:           Mac OS X 14.1 x86_64
```

Anyone that have experienced similar issues, please help.

I am using the lastest version of Android Studio for macOS.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Gradle 7.5, but you run Gradle with Java 21.

This is not supported.

Gradle 8.5 will be the first version supporting running with Java 21.

For Gradle 7.5 you have to use something between Java 8 and Java 18 as documented at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html.